# Не работает аудит создания папок в Windows 7

Tags: windows, аудит

Хочу настроить аудит файловых операций в Windows 7, столкнулся с тем, что не работает (не приходят события в оснастку "Просмотр событий") аудит создания папок. По удалению файла/папки событие приходит, по созданию **файла** тоже приходит, по созданию **папки** - нет. Проверил на 2 машинах с Windows 7 и на одной с 2008 R2 - поведение идентичное.
В политиках аудит файловой системы включён (Политика "Локальный компьютер" (Local Computer Policy) -> Конфигурация Windows (Windows Settings) -> Параметры безопасности (Security Settings)-> Конфигурация расширенной политики аудита (Advanced audit policy configuration) -> Политика аудита системы - Объект локальной групповой политики (System audit policies - Local group policy object) -> Доступ к объектам (Object Access)-> Аудит файловой системы: успех, отказ (Audit file system: Success, Failure)).
Аудит тестовой папки включён, для групп "Все" ("Everyone") выбраны события "Создание файлов/запись данных", "Создание папок/дозапись данных", "Удаление подпапок и файлов", "Удаление". В некоторых руководствах советуют ещё включить событие "Чтение атрибутов", пробовал включать - ничего не меняется (кроме того, что в "Просмотре событий" появляются события "Чтение атрибутов").
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким поведением?